# Array keeps on adding same value in interceptor

Tags: java, spring-boot, instance-variables, local-variables

What I am trying to do is build a simple interceptor that checks whether the user has specified a language attribute in the headers or not. I have configured everything and all is running well but if I submit the request more than one time, I see that the error message got added in the array again and now is showing twice.

This is the code for the interceptor:

```
public class LanguageInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private List errors = new ArrayList();
    private BadRequestException badRequestException = new BadRequestException();
    private BadRequestExceptionData badRequestExceptionData = new BadRequestExceptionData();

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        String LocaleLang = request.getHeader("Accept-Language");
        if(null == LocaleLang) {
            badRequestException.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
            badRequestException.setTitle("Illegal request");
            errors.add("No language attribute specified in your request!");
            badRequestExceptionData.setPageSize(errors);
            badRequestException.setErrors(badRequestExceptionData);

            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
            response.getWriter().write(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(badRequestException));
            response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Example response:

```
{
    "status": 400,
    "errors": {
        "pageSize": [
            "No language specified in your request!",
            "No language specified in your request!"
        ]
    },
    "title": "Illegal request"
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or do I have to empty the object when the preHandle function is done? My apologies if this question sounds a bit dull, I am still new to Java and Spring boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `LanguageInterceptor` has been [instantiated as a singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201728/how-are-spring-handlerinterceptors-instantiated). Shift all these three variables inside the method, `preHandle` to make them [local instead of instance variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088299/what-is-the-difference-between-local-and-instance-variables-in-java).

```
List errors = new ArrayList();
BadRequestException badRequestException = new BadRequestException();
BadRequestExceptionData badRequestExceptionData = new BadRequestExceptionData();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `LanguageInterceptor` is a singleton bean, the errors List will keep the status on every request.

You can solve this issue by declaring the list inside the method.

Also, I recommend you do the same for the exceptions.